# Dynamic generation new object

Tags: oop, game-engine, 2d-games, ursina

I can't create a new cube without disappearance of original cube in my tetris game. When I'm using this method my first cube disappears and the new one appears. I want make two similar cubes with similar methods
There is my code:

```py
from ursina import *
from random import randint


class CubeSprite(object):
    dawn = 0
    e = Sprite(model='square', color=color.orange, scale_y=0.25, scale_x=0.25, position=(0, 0, 0))
    e1 = Sprite(model='square', color=color.green, scale_y=0.25, scale_x=0.25,  position=(.25, 0, 0))
    e2 = Sprite(model='square', color=color.yellow, scale_y=0.25, scale_x=0.25,  position=(0, -.25, 0))
    e3 = Sprite(model='square', color=color.red, scale_y=0.25, scale_x=0.25,  position=(.25, -.25, 0))

    def generation(self):
        x_position = randint(-3, 4)
        self.e.position = (x_position, 4, 0)
        self.e1.position = (x_position + .25, 4, 0)
        self.e2.position = (x_position, 3.75, 0)
        self.e3.position = (x_position+.25, 3.75, 0)

    def movement(self):
        if self.dawn < 1:
            if held_keys['d'] and self.e3.x < 6.75:
                self.e.x += 0.25
                self.e1.x += 0.25
                self.e2.x += 0.25
                self.e3.x += 0.25
            if held_keys['a'] and self.e.x > -6.75:
                self.e.x -= 0.25
                self.e1.x -= 0.25
                self.e2.x -= 0.25
                self.e3.x -= 0.25
            self.e.y -= 0.25
            self.e1.y -= 0.25
            self.e2.y -= 0.25
            self.e3.y -= 0.25

cube = CubeSprite()
cube.generation()
cube2 = object.__new__(CubeSprite)
cube2.generation()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using class attributes for your positions that are shared by all objects of this type. That's why you can't distinguish the two sprites. Instead, make them proper instance attributes which are defined in the constructor and create them as normal objects:

```py
class CubeSprite(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.dawn = 0
        x_position = randint(-3, 4)
        self.e = Sprite(model='quad', color=color.orange, scale_y=0.25, scale_x=0.25, position=(x_position, 0, 0))
        self.e1 = Sprite(model='quad', color=color.green, scale_y=0.25, scale_x=0.25,  position=(x_position+.25, 0, 0))
        self.e2 = Sprite(model='quad', color=color.yellow, scale_y=0.25, scale_x=0.25,  position=(x_position, -.25, 0))
        self.e3 = Sprite(model='quad', color=color.red, scale_y=0.25, scale_x=0.25,  position=(x_position+.25, -.25, 0))

cube = CubeSprite()
cube2 = CubeSprite()
```

You may want to read up on the basics of object oriented design in Python.